# Get unique row with many conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a history table of ordered products

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | IdProduct  | status |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 100        | 1      |
|  2 | 100        | 2      |
|  3 | 100        | 3      |
|    |            |        |
|  4 | 200        | 1      |
|  5 | 200        | 2      |
|    |            |        |
|  6 | 300        | 1      |
|  7 | 300        | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I want to get only the products who have the status `2` but not `3`

```
+----+------------+
| id | IdProduct  |
+----+------------+
|  5 | 200        |
|    |            |
|  7 | 300        |
+----+------------+
```

How can I achieve this using a Linq request

Comment: Why would you not simply use SQL? As in, use SQL and do this via PetaPoco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linq to sql you can do:

```
var result = history.GroupBy(item => item.IdProduct)
                    .Where(grp => grp.Any(item => item.Status == 2) &&
                                 !grp.Any(item => item.Status == 3))
                    .Select(grp => new { 
                        IdProduct = grp.Key, 
                        Id = grp.Max(item => item.Id) 
                    });
```

Or:

```
var result = history.GroupBy(item => item.IdProduct)
                    .Where(grp => grp.Any(item => item.Status == 2) &&
                                 !grp.Any(item => item.Status == 3))
                    .Select(grp => grp.Where(item => ite.Status == 2).FirstOrDefault());
```

*In your case both these should return the same because the max(id) correleted with the result you wanted*

If you know each status exists only once then you can try the following. The idea is that status 3 items equal -1, 2 equals 1 and the rest 0. Only groups that have status 2 but not 3 will have the result of 1

```
var result = history.Select(item => new { Item = item, Valid = item.Status == 2 ? 1 : item.Status == 3 ? -1 : 0 })
                    .GroupBy(item => item.Item.IdProduct)
                    .Where(grp => grp.Sum(item => item.Valid) == 1) 
                    .Select(item => item.Item);
```

Answer (score 2):

I didnt read the last line in question *How can I achieve this using a Linq request* may be that reason for downvote..

Will keep this answer if someone is looking to solve it in `SQL`

---

Here is one way using `Group by` and `Having` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  IdProduct IN (SELECT IdProduct
                     FROM   Yourtable
                     GROUP  BY IdProduct
                     HAVING Count(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) = 0
                            AND Count(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0)
       AND Status = 2
```

`Count(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) = 0`

This condition is to make sure `status = 3` does not exist any row for each `ID`

`Count(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0`

This condition is to make sure alteast one row with `status = 2` for each `ID`

Comment: I honestly don't understand why people want to use Linq - it's as if they don't believe in "simplest is the best", a la Occam's Razor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,IdProduct int,status int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 1 , 100 , 1 ),
( 2 , 100 , 2 ),
( 3 , 100 , 3 ),
( 4 , 200 , 1 ),
( 5 , 200 , 2 ),
( 6 , 300 , 1 ),
( 7 , 300 , 2 )


Select Id,IdProduct
    From (
        Select Id
                ,IdProduct
                ,MaxStatus = max(Status) over (Partition By IdProduct)
            From @YourTable
            Where Status in (2,3)
        ) A
    Where MaxStatus = 2
```

Returns

```
Id  IdProduct
5   200
7   300
```

Comment: Add this record it will fail `( 5 , 200 , 4 )` ;)

Comment: @Prdp Very true.. assuming there is a status 4+

Comment: Whatever +1 for using aggregated window function I love that feature

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for the heads up quick fix  Where Status in (2,3)

Comment: @Prdp Not ashamed to admit I did a little dance when they were introduced.  It wasn't pretty.